# Simple Ajax in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

In a Laravel app, I need to update some data in the database after a button is clicked, without reloading the page, thus requiring ajax. No data needs to parsed, only a function in one of the controllers should be invoked, so it's the simplest kind of ajax request.

Based on [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_ajax.htm) example, I set up the following, but nothing happens. No error, no response from the check `alert('success!')`, nothing.

---

QUESTION: why does nothing happen? Could it be that the Javascript is not recognized at al?

---

**Head**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Routes - web.php**

```
Route::post('/notificationsSeen','NotificationController@seen');
```

**Controller - NotificationController.php**

```
public function seen() {
    $userNotifications = Notification::where('user_id',Auth::id())
                    ->where('status','new')
                    ->update(array('status' => 'seen'));

    return;
}
```

**View**

```
<button type="button" id="notifications"></button>

<script>
  $("#notifications").on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url:'/notificationsSeen',
       data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
       success:function(data){
          alert('success!');
       }
    });
  });
</script>
```

---

### EDIT: WORKING SOLUTION

Change the contents of the box above labeled "View" to the following:

```
<button type="button" id="notifications"></button>

<script>
  (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#notifications').on('click', function() {

            $.ajax({
                url: '/notificationsSeen',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}' },
                success:function(){alert('success!');},
                error: function (){alert('error');}, 
            });

            });

        });
        }(jQuery));
</script>
```

Comment: Check your request data in laravel controller dd($requet->all());

Comment: check response with `return response()->json($request->all());`

Comment: I did this, but with no result, it appears it doesn't come as far as the controller at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your AJAX request, data is not a string. It is a key value pair. So use

```
data: { _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}' }
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed this. But a problem seems to occur before this point. The console says for the `$.ajax`: **undefined is not a function near $.ajax**...

Comment: I fixed this problem by including the whole script inside `
(function ($) {}(jQuery));` **The server now responds with a 500 error though**

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass the csrf token like this:

```
data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
```

You have to store it in a HTML meta tag:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then automatically add the token to all request headers:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $("#notifications").on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/notificationsSeen',
            data: {status: 'seen'},
            success:function(data){
                alert('success!');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Controller:

```
public function seen() {
    $userNotifications = Notification::where('user_id',Auth::id())
                    ->where('status','new')
                    ->update(array('status' => request()->input('status')));

    return ['success' => true];
}
```

Comment: Thanks YouneL! I tried this, but nothing changed: there is no response whatsoever. No database change, no alert, no error...

Comment: Try to put the route `Route::post('/notificationsSeen','NotificationController@seen');` on top of all other routes

Comment: The `$("#notifications").on('click', function() {}` works fine but the console says for the `$.ajax`: **undefined is not a function near $.ajax**

Comment: I fixed this problem by including the whole script inside `
(function ($) {}(jQuery));` **The server now responds with a 500 error though**